# SharePoint - Wcf encoding

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, encoding, url-encoding

What is the best practice for string encoding?
I have search filter user control and on button click event, at the end, I have:

```
Response.Redirect("....page.aspx?filterField=companyName&fieldValue=unilever");
```

I tried "Server.UrlEncode", "Server.UrlPathEncode", "SPEncode.UrlEncode", "SPEncode.UrlEncodeAsUrl" and I still had problems with characters ", &, <, >

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem for all characters?
Perhaps third party library for SP and WCF...??? (WCF is 4.0 .net framework and SP is 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

The keys and values in a query string must be url encoded, so it's like:

```
UrlEncode(key) '=' UrlEncode(value) [ '&' UrlEncode(key) '=' UrlEncode(value)] ...
```

However, your particular example remains unchanged after this processing. So let's say `"filterField"` must be `"lö&l"` and `"fieldValue"` must be `"ä&sd"`. Then the encoded string is:

```
filterField=l%C3%B6%26l&fieldValue=%C3%A4%26sd
```

Note that the whole thing is not encoded at once, but keys and values separately.